# How to join four mysql tables?

Tags: mysql, join

I have four mysql tables and I want to do join queries on them to display selected data from all four tables.

```
table1 `t1key, t1a t1b t1c t1d`
table2 `t2key, t2a t2b t2c t2d`
table3 `t3key t3a t3b t3c t3d`
table4 `t4key, t4a t4b t4c t4d`
```

I want to display 
t1a, t1c, t2a, t2b, t2d, t3a, t3b, t4b, t4c, t4d

I did query like this:

```
SELECT t1a, t1c, t2a, t2b, t2d, t3a, t3b, t4b, t4c, t4d FROM table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 ON table1.t1key=table2.t2key
LEFT OUTER JOIN table3 ON table2.t2key=table3.t3key
LEFT OUTER JOIN table4 ON table3.t3key=table4.t4key
```

However I only see values from table1, table2 and table3. table4 values are shown null. I checked the document but I still couldn't figure it out.

Comment: oke your question is not pretty clear ? but let ask **what field from each table has same value** and please give some dummmy data,

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using the left outer join, if the result returned is NULL then the condition of:

table3.t3key=table4.t4key

Yields no results, in short there are no rows in table4 that match table3.